# ImageList poor quality image

Tags: c#, imagelist

Images in ImageList displayed in my custom TabControl have a poor quality :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAJkC.png

Originals images quality (check the right image for differences) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6P3X.png

Originals have a size of 24x24.
I add my ImageList, change Size parameter by 24x24, set ColorDepth to 32 (J'ai essayé avec 8, 16 ...) and after i add my images.

Code to display image in my custom TabControl :

```
// Icon
        if (ImageList != null) {
            if (tp.ImageIndex != -1) {
                Image i = ImageList.Images[tp.ImageIndex];
                Point p = new Point(12, r.Y + ((ItemSize.Width / 2) - (i.Height / 2)));
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, p);
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you sure you uploaded the right images?

Comment: Yes, first images it's in my tabcontrol and second image are  original examples